# как настроить в qbrush цвет?

Tags: qt, qpainter

Пытаюсь настроить цвет фона  :

```
     QBrush maska(QColor(48,172,220,120),Qt::SolidPattern);      // для маски
    painter.setBrush(maska);                                           // задаём цвет фона
```

вот так всё работает цвет фона настраивается .

[image: Screenshot_20220124_165105.png]

А вот так цвет фона не настраивается а почемуто заполняется нулями

вот код вызова :

```
case Qt::Key_A:
    if(_myTexpr.substrate)
        setSubstrate(false, 100, 100, 100, 100);
    else
        setSubstrate(true, 100, 100, 100, 100);


void wgt_line::setSubstrate(bool val, int rgb0, int rgb1, int rgb2, int rgb3 )
{
    _myTexpr.substrate = val;

    _myTexpr.substrate_t = true; // включаем датчик

    qDebug() << "setSubstrate(bool val, int rgb0, int rgb1, int rgb2, int rgb3 )";
    _myTexpr. rgb[0] = rgb0;
    _myTexpr. rgb[1] = rgb1;
    _myTexpr. rgb[2] = rgb2;
    _myTexpr. rgb[3] = rgb3;
 
}
```

вот код :

```
if(_myTexpr.substrate_t == true)
    {
        color_maska.fromRgb(_myTexpr.rgb[0], _myTexpr.rgb[1], _myTexpr.rgb[2], _myTexpr.rgb[3]);
//         color_maska(_myTexpr.rgb[0], _myTexpr.rgb[1], _myTexpr.rgb[2], _myTexpr.rgb[3]);
        maska.setColor(color_maska);    maska.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
//         maska(color_maska,Qt::SolidPattern);      // для маски
         qDebug() << "_myTexpr.suqqqqq";
    }
    if(_myTexpr.substrate_t == false)
        {
            qDebug() << "_myTexpr.substrate_t1";
             color_maska.fromRgb(48,172,220,120);
             maska.setColor(color_maska);    maska.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    //         maska(color_maska,Qt::SolidPattern);      // для маски
        }
    // задаём цвет фона
    if(_myTexpr.substrate == true)
        painter.setBrush(maska);
```

[image: Screenshot_20220124_165549.png]

---

вот этот код работает

```
QBrush maska1(QColor(48,172,220,120),Qt::SolidPattern);      // для маски
    painter.setBrush(maska1);                                   // задаём цвет фона
```

этот нет

```
QBrush maska;                   // фон
QColor color_maska;            // задаём цвет фона 

color_maska.fromRgb(48,172,220,120);
maska.setColor(color_maska);
maska.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
painter.setBrush(maska);
```

**НЕ ЗНАЮ ПОЧЕМУ :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QBrush maska;                   // фон
QColor color_maska;            // задаём цвет фона 

color_maska.fromRgb(48,172,220,120);
maska.setColor(color_maska);
maska.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
painter.setBrush(maska);
```

Этот код не работает, потому что вы используете статический метод (fromRgb), который не модифицирует состояние объекта. Попробуйте так:

```
QBrush maska;                   // фон
QColor color_maska = QColor::fromRgb(48,172,220,120);
maska.setColor(color_maska);
maska.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
painter.setBrush(maska);
```